# Cannot see "Custom" web part folder SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am new on SP 2010 and VS 2010.
After installation of SP, I am able to surf to localhost, and see a page called "Home".
I made a test Visual Web Part, and it deployed fine.
I am able to edit the home page, and see and add the web part from the Custom folder.

I then made a new site, called Foo Site. When I edit its home page, I do not see the web part Custom folder, so I may choose my web part and add it.
Why does the Custom folder show up on one page, when adding a web part, and not on another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you activate the feature on your new site? When you deploy from Visual Studio it will automatically do this based on where your project is configured to deploy it to (which is why you see it on your original site).

Comment: I did not intentionally. Can you give me a push in the right direction on where to do so, like in the Central Admin tool, or??

Comment: Go to your Site. Select Site Settings. Select Manage Site Features. Activate your feature.